# How to get View From child of Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract?

Tags: php, zend-framework

Just need to set up navigation per admin module, I know it is strange and not really good practice may be but I need to set it for admin part.
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$viewRenderer = Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker::getStaticHelper('viewRenderer');
if (null === $viewRenderer->view) {
    $viewRenderer->initView();
}
$view = $viewRenderer->view;
```

This excerpt is taken from `Zend_Layout::getView()`;

If you are going to need the layout anyway too, you could extend `Zend_Layout_Controller_Plugin_Layout` in stead of `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract`.

Then, to access the layout do:

```
$this->getLayout();
```

And to access the view, do:

```
$this->getLayout()->getView();
```

Comment: thanks, btw does the Zend_Controller_Action_HelperBroker implement some well known design patters, just the word broker sound very like a pattern ?

Comment: I guess it implements the Broker Pattern. ;-) Not farmiliar with it to be honoust. So I couldn't tell you much more about it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I retrieved like

```
$layout = Zend_Layout::getMvcInstance();
$navigation = $layout->getView()->navigation();
```

inside the plugin that extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
thanks thoug, still better methods are welcome